# Getting a SQL Column's data based on another Column's data in C#

Tags: c#, asp.net

I'm working with a table that has (for the purposes of this question) 2 columns.  One column can take a value of 1, 2, 3, 4 or 5 (simply for indicating the category of the data in the other column -- there are 5 categories possible).  The other column simply has a string in it, such as "Grant1".

The title of the text column is "Title" and the title of the integer column is "Category"

What I need to do is sort the rows based on the Category column, and then put all of the data from each row in a list, in C#.  This way I can later on use the List to look at all of the Title data that fell under that category.

This is what I have so far:

```
DataTable dt = AnimalGrants.Tables["AnimalGrants"];
    string columnName = "Title";
    List<string> ListOfAnimalGrantTitles = new List<string>();
    int i = 0;
    foreach (DataRow dr in dt.Rows)
    {
        ListOfAnimalGrantTitles.Add(dr.Table.Columns[i].ToString());
    }
```

What I have is not working properly...  I want to be pretty certain this works before uploading.  Can any SQL or C# expert help me understand how to accomplish this?  I think I have a good start here, but am afraid of getting stuck on a syntax bug.

```
DataSet AnimalGrants = tp.GetItems("CFHudsonGrants", "WHERE Category = 1;", "");
```

Comment: Are you sorting in SQL first, or do you want to sort in C#?

Comment: I would prefer to sort in C#.  Although, I don't really need to sort in any specific order, just by category.  In my WHERE clause, I didn't do any sorting.

Comment: So basically all I need to do is separate all the possible 5 categories from the SQL table into different Lists... i bet this is really easy

Comment: " I want to be pretty certain this works before uploading." Is this a school assignment?

Comment: Much simpler in SQL.  Show your SQL query and we can put the `order by` in there.

Comment: Ok I will post my SQL Query.  I didn't know the order by could do this.

Comment: No Keith this is for a nonprofit education grants website :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm a little confused but the code below should create a list of the values in column one, but order that list by the values in column 2:

```
DataTable dt = AnimalGrants.Tables["AnimalGrants"];
string columnName = "Title";
List<string> ListOfAnimalGrantTitles = new List<string>();
int i = 0;
foreach (DataRow dr in dt.Rows.Cast<DataRow>().OrderBy(t => t[1]))
{
    ListOfAnimalGrantTitles.Add(dr[0]);
}
```

That said, you would probably be better off just sorting this in your SQL query...